# Go back to previous activity in click into DrawerLayout?

Tags: android

I have a action bar.
When I click the home button in the action bar it shows me a list.

the first problem:

When the draw layout is empty .
And home user clicks the button , a blank page is displayed from right to left .
If the user clicks the back button phone , draw layout disappear ,
Back to main page .
But when i put a list view into draw layout:
After the home user clicks the button , a list is displayed

When the user clicks the back button phone , this time not due to homepage
And the program exits . Main activity is killed .

second problem:

When I click on one of the list items (settings) inside the ACTIVITY SETTING:
My problem is when the user clicks the OK button after setting, the program exits
(doesn't go back Main.Activity).

My English is not good.sorry
 Java code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
      mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
      mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_qustion);
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);


    ImageButton imag_home = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.image_home);
    imag_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
        }
    });


    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    Myadapter2 adapter2=new Myadapter2(getBaseContext(), title, draw);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
            {

                Intent x2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoveActivity.class);
                startActivity(x2);
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                Intent x=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
                x.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivityForResult(x, request_Code);


            }
    //............


            }



        }
    });
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter2);
  //list view into draw layout


    Myadapter adapter=new Myadapter(getBaseContext());
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                //......

            }

        }
    });
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //main list view 

}
```

I have a class Myadapte2 like class Myadapter in package

SettingActivity:

```
    Button ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    Button cancell=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_no);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
        finish();
        }
    });
    cancell.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
```

activity_main :

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#82c6fb"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_qustion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>




</LinearLayout>
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#eaeaea"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It is hard to say something. These parts of code should work as well. Are you sure that you don't finish your MainActivity somewhere else?

Comment: I added all the code in question